# Concrete 5 - Where to put .htcaccess

Tags: html, .htaccess, concrete5

I have made my own theme in concrete 5 and produced a 600 page site, however im looking at speeding the site up according to Google Site Speed.

I did place the ..htcaccess file in the "themes" directory which contains my custom theme, however I think this was causing my site to have 500 internal server errors.

Where is the correct place of putting the .htcaccess file in the Concrete5 directory? Even better, does anyone have tips for what to include inside the .htcaccess. I have most of the content for it, but its mostly copied from gzip sites etc

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you are doing in your .htaccess file and what the intention is.  Usually though, you'll want to put it in your web root, i.e. place it at the same level as your main index file.

Comment: That's what I did initially, but obviously concrete 5 has loads of files for the CMS and was wondering if it was meant to go into somewhere else rather than the themes directory*

Answer (score 0):

If you enable the "pretty url" feature of C5 via Dashboard > System & Settings > SEO & Statistics > Pretty URLs , it will generate an htaccess file for you at the proper place on your server (at the web root, as @danmullen mentions in his answer). Putting .htaccess in your theme directory will just not work, period.